# Are the larger base cards available for Smash Up?

Tags: custom-game-pieces, smash-up

In Geek & Sundry's episode of [Table Top](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=4ZpMEVQYBO8&t=312) featuring Smash Up, they were using larger base cards that featured a built-in counter for the break point:

[image: Ninja Dojo expanded base card]

I just bought Smash Up, and it came with base cards that lack the counter, and are the same size as the rest of the deck cards for the game.

Are these bigger versions available?  Can I download them from somewhere and print my own, or does the manufacturer offer them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in the meantime you can use these printable ones :)
http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/91736/smash-up-base-mats

Answer (score 8):

**Edit:**
*It appears that the manufacturer has decided that it was economically unfeasible to release the new base cards*.

Todd Rowland, one of the Game Designers/Publishers, has confirmed that the base cards in the episode were made by AEG (the publisher), and [will be made available later this year](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/993835/tabletops-large-base-cards):

> No we made them, and we've made them for AL9K and Cthulhu as well.

and

> We will make them available later this year.

Comment: Too bad they decided not to make them after all :(

Answer (score -3):

A good tip I use is buy 3 combination locks from the doller store that look like this [http://www.amazon.com/BestDealUSA-Combination-Luggage-Padlock-Durable/dp/B007VXKXQ0/ref=sr_1_2?s=hardware&ie=UTF8&qid=1427741474&sr=1-2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007VXKXQ0)... they are tiny but can be used to keep track of a bases points and fit in the game box, total cost $3 - total gamechanger